# How can I modify this MySQL query to get a particular data structure?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have two simple tables:

Photos :

```
photoid | filename            | albumid
1       | something.jpg       |    1
2       | somethingelse.jpg   |    1
```

And an Albums table :

```
  albumid   | album_name        | owner_id
    1       | My Holiday 2012   |    1
    2       | My Holiday 2013   |    6
```

And I want to get all photos contained within all albums for a given `owner_id`

I can do the following :

```
select albums.*, photos.*
from photo_albums as albums
left join photos as photos
on albums.albumid = photos.albumid
where albums.owner_id = :owner_id
```

This will return 2 rows, on for each photo as well as the relevant album data.

However what I would like to do is return only on row per album.  With the photos rows nested within each album row.

Returning output similar to the following:

```
[{
    albumid : 1,
    album_name : My Holiday 2012,
    owner_id : 1,
    photos : {
                 photoid : 1,
                 filename : something.jpg
             },
             {
                 photoid : 2,
                 filename : somethingelse.jpg
             }   
}]
```

Is there an easy and efficient way to do this within the MySQL query itself?  If so how?  Or alternatively am I better taking the complete row data from the original query and constructing the data into this output by looping through the rows in php?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't do it by modifying SQL query.

I see two ways to achieve your goal:

1. Postprocess your output to build needed array structure.
2. Use a [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (Object-relational mapping) to automatically map your query results to objects. For example, see [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org).

Comment: Fine.  that's really all i needed to be certain of.  Thanks @barbashov i'll award you the answer when I am able. :)